# Apps Script: Is it possible to display only Last 5 rows of an array table? or reverse the array table result and show only the 1st 5 Rows?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I just connect my Apps Script (Web app) to  google sheet API and configure a search function.
Is it possible to show only the last 5 rows of the results? or reverse the result then get Only the 1st 5 rows?

Thank you for any Suggestions.

P.S- I got the code from these site.
https://www.bpwebs.com/create-web-forms-to-get-data-from-google-sheets/?fbclid=IwAR14AyU4lHsWmQBpn59waMq74-E9un2vm1r8CWHU-Dqmb8XQApzHx97thQg

[Here is the sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAkyB.png)

Comment: I already Reverse the table result, Any idea how I can only show the First 5 Rows?

Answer (score 0):

See [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Answer (score 0):

When you get a table in Apps Scripts using the [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method, you get an array of arrays. You can perform the following operations to get the last 5 results:

```
var values = ss.getRange("A1:C10").getValues()
values.reverse()
var result = values.slice(0,5)
```

### References

- [Range: getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)